# Sequelize eager loading: hasMany include parent

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following two models:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var ChatRoom = sequelize.define('ChatRoom', {
    status: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        ChatRoom.hasMany(models.User)
        ChatRoom.hasMany(models.Message)
      }
    }
  });

  return ChatRoom;
};

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    friendly_id: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        User.hasMany(models.Message)
      }
    }
  });

  return User;
};
```

When I fetch a user, I want to fetch the associated `ChatRoom` as well. I tried the following

```
models.User.findOne({
  where: {messenger_id: senderID},
  include: [{model: models.ChatRoom}]
}).then(function(user) { ... })
```

But I get this error

```
ChatRoom is not associated to User!
```

Answer (score 0):

When defining the `User` model, you should also associate this model with the `ChatRoom` model.

I don't know your business logic, but I suppose the `associate` method of the `User` model should look like:

```
associate: function(models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Message);
    User.belongsTo(models.ChatRoom, {
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        foreignKey: {
            allowNull: false
        }
    });
}
```